# Details Query in pg_stat_statements

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

In pg_stat_statements output ("query" field):

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?

How can I get the details of "?" from query in pg_stat_statements?
Can anybody tell me about this, because I want to track if anyone execute some query.
Can we also know which ip address this query execute from? so I can monitor if anyone make some modification data in database.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pg_stat_monitor](https://github.com/percona/pg_stat_monitor), it has that feature.